# Building Universal (fat) framework for an SDK/library: can I reuse frameworks built for XCFramework?

Tags: xcodebuild, xcframework, lipo, ios-universal-framework

Currently I am only building XCFramework for SDK. I was asked to also create a legacy Universal (fat) framework.

The XCFramework creation includes 2 stages (taking iOS-only build here just to simplify):

1. **Build `.framework` archives**, using the following command with `SDK="iphoneos"` and `SDK="iphonesimulator"`

```
xcodebuild archive \
    -scheme "${SCHEME}" \
    -archivePath "${ARCHIVE_PATH}" \
    -sdk "${SDK}" \
    -configuration "Release" \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
    clean
```

2. And then creating XCFramework with `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` command, and including both of the frameworks created in step 1.

From what I understand, creation of Universal library includes the same 2 steps: building frameworks, and then packaging them with `lipo -create`.

So I wonder if building frameworks for Universal (fat) framework is any different than building them for XCFramework? In other words, can I reuse the results of Step 1 above, and only add `lipo -create` instead of `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` as a second step?
Or are there any different requirements for `.framework` creation for Universal framework, comparing to XCFramework?

Unfortunately I didn't find any official guide. Thanks in advance.